# Font Awesome icons size

Tags: jquery, css, font-awesome

I am using a Font Awesome icon in a button on my page that is intended to reload the page.  When a user hovers over the button, I want the icon to spin and become larger (just the icon, not the button text) so I did this:

```
$("#clearButton").hover(function() {
$("#clearIcon").addClass('fa-spin');
$("#clearIcon").addClass('fa-lg');
});
```

This works, but when the icon gets larger it makes the button slightly larger and pushes the button text to the side. I am sure I am not setting the padding and/or margins correctly. Any help?

Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/2avoj27e/1/

Thank you!

Comment: Your jsFiddle is not currently working. Get it to the point that it is recreating the error you describe and let us know.

Comment: Here you go: https://jsfiddle.net/2avoj27e/2/. In HTML when you increase the font size, it will just push everything after or below it away. I updated this fiddle to make the icon have `position:absolute`

Comment: BTW, you originally included a link to bootstrap.css that wasn't working. I used a CDN-hosted css file in my fiddle.

Comment: That worked, thank you!

Comment: @Kodos You should repost your comment as an answer.